# How to fill data from web api into Custom listView in android

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, listview, custom-lists

I want to fetch data from web api and fill in `ListView` in android. I have already learnt how to call web api and successfully done in my app, but the problem is how to show in my `ListView`? I want to fill data as in shown in below image.

[image].

How can I fill as exactly as in image? Which components are used in `ListView`? If this is not a `ListView` then which layout is this? I also want to know how can I use above buttons(Overview, matches, Teams, standings ). I want to change the data when I press different buttons. Please share your experiences and suggest me some learning sources.

Comment: are you able to fetch the data from API?

Comment: Please share your response to check what data you get from api

Answer (score 0):

- create a custom java class describing a single Item as an object that will contains a number of variables for storing data that will come from web API.
- create a custom layout (list_item.xml) contains two ImageViews and 3 textviews .
- store your API data in an Arraylist of type (YourCustomJavaObjectclass).
- create a custom Arrayadapter , then inflate the (list_item.xml) inside the getView method and then bind your views with data from the ArrayList.
  For more info read this article 
  https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView
- For creating these (Overview, matches, Teams, standings) you have to use ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter , for more Read this https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter